# Substitute numbers in a random IP address port with space

Tags: text-processing, ip-address

I have a file with IP and port numbers. I would like to take out the port number and leave the IP alone.

```
xyz  10.93.10.13:58160).
xyz 10.93.10.13:58161).
xyz 10.18.104.181:12466).
xyz 10.93.10.13:60585).
wxy 10.93.10.13:60586).
wxy 10.93.10.13:60587).
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]:33955).
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]:33957).
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]:33961).
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]:33962).
```

expected output

```
xyz 10.93.10.13
xyz 10.93.10.13
xyz 10.18.104.181
xyz 10.93.10.13
wxy 10.93.10.13
wxy 10.93.10.13
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
```

i tried a lame procedure which won't work

```
cat 1.txt|grep -v [:12312]
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, useless use of `cat`.  Secondly, `grep` only searches; it does not change anything.  You want `sed` here:

```
$ sed -E 's/:[0-9]+.*/ /' input
xyz  10.93.10.13
xyz 10.93.10.13
xyz 10.18.104.181
xyz 10.93.10.13
wxy 10.93.10.13
wxy 10.93.10.13
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
ADMIN loopback[127.0.0.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/' filename` should do the trick. Match everything before the colon and return that in the substitution.